# Assign two elements and form a list in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, assign

Within my project, I have to define a function, in which I get two lists below and one hour, extracted through an earlier file (these are completely arbitrary, but the sequence of the data is the same). The "return" command must return a list with the operator's name, followed by the customer's name.

```
[('Ricardo Tavares', 'portuguese', '(mobiles; printers)', '14:15', 42), ('Carl Thompson', 'english', '(laptops)', '14:17', 54), ('Nuria Castro', 'spanish', '(cameras; hifi)', '14:24', 37), ('Giovanni Olivetti', 'italian', '(laptops; bimby; hifi)', '14:52', 21), ('Georg Muller', 'deutsch', '(cameras)', '15:05', 31)]
```

```
[('Henry Miller', 'english', 'laptops', 'premium', 3), ('Francois Greenwich', 'spanish', 'cameras', 'premium', 6), ('Ricardo Carvalho', 'portuguese', 'refrigerators', 'premium', 2)]
```

The objective is to assign operators (first list) to the customers (second list). Assignment must be done according to the field of knowledge (eg. mobiles, printers) and the operator's language (eg. portuguese, english) as well as the customer's help topic (eg. laptops, cameras) and the language they both speak (eg. english, spanish). In addition, it is necessary to keep in mind that customers who are "premium" must be served first than the other "fremium". The assignment of the operators to the customers must be done according to the number of minutes they have worked (the last tuple value of each list element) as well as the last time they answered a customer (eg. 14:15).

With all these conditions, in addition to getting a bit confusing, I can not quite figure out which is the most efficient way to solve this code without being too defensive when programming!

This is what I have right now, but the list stays blank.

```
def assign_tasks(operators, requests, current_time):

operators = sorted(operators, key=itemgetter(3), reverse=False)
requests = sorted(requests, key=itemgetter(3), reverse=True)
tasks = []

langr = 0 #Variable that gets the language of the request's file (customer's language)
lango = 0 #Variable that gets the language of the operator's file (operator's language) 
for i in range(0, len(requests)):
    langr = requests[i][1]                                   #What language does the customer speaks?
    for k in range(0, len(operators)):
        lango = operators[k][1]                              #What language does the operator speaks?
        if langr == lango:                                   #Do they speak the same language?
            for j in range(0, len(operators[k][2])):
                if operators[k][2][j] == requests[i][2]:     # The operator knows how to solve the client's problem? If yes, then group them together.
                    tasks.append((current_time, operators[k][0], requests[i][0]))
                    operators.remove(operators[k])
                    requests.remove(requests[i])
print(tasks) 
return tasks
```

```
operators = [('Leticia Ferreira', 'portuguese', '(laptops)', '11:03', 15), ('Atilio Moreno', 'portuguese', '(laptops)', '10:58', 104), ('Ruth Falk', 'german', '(phones; hifi)', '11:06', 150), ('Marianne Thibault', 'french', '(phones)', '11:09', 230), ('Mariana Santana', 'portuguese', '(phones)', '11:11', 230), ('Beate Adenauer', 'german', '(hifi; phones)', '11:12', 140), ('Romana Cerveny', 'czech', '(phones)', '11:13', 213), ('Zdenka Sedlak', 'czech', '(phones)', '11:13', 56)]
requests = [('Christina Holtzer', 'german', 'hifi', 'fremium', 7), ('Andrej Hlavac', 'czech', 'phones', 'fremium', 9), ('Dulce Chaves', 'portuguese', 'laptops', 'fremium', 15), ('Otavio Santiago', 'portuguese', 'laptops', 'fremium', 15), ('Dina Silveira', 'portuguese', 'phones', 'fremium', 9), ('Rafael Kaluza', 'slovenian', 'laptops', 'fremium', 13), ('Sabina Rosario', 'portuguese', 'laptops', 'premium', 10), ('Nuno Rodrigues', 'portuguese', 'laptops', 'fremium', 12), ('Feliciano Santos', 'portuguese', 'phones', 'fremium', 12)]

current_time = "14:55 06:11:2017"

assign_tasks(operators, requests, current_time)
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: What is your expected output? You forgot to show this.

Comment: Show us the expected outcome for your input examples.

Comment: Also, *what have you tried*?

Comment: The only way to solve challenging problems, and become a better programmer, is to just dive in, and get your hands dirty. If defensive programming is your intuitive approach, then start with that, and go from there. And if you get really stuck, come back here, with a solid attempt to show for, and we'd be happy to help you out.

Comment: [But what is this ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673148/how-can-i-write-a-list-of-tuples-on-a-new-file#comment82305186_47673148)

He edited, but I remember this post and I think he posted the exact same thing. You should talk with your classmates. You probably both had the same idea. I might be wrong : but the 2 subjects are too close not to ask. ;)

Comment: Output: 16:56, François Greenwich, Ramon Diaz

Comment: I think you need to break this problem down into components. There seems to be a lot of conditional logic on the assignment of operator to customer. Why can't you just use a bunch of `if` statements? What does the final list need to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't coded in python in a long time, so my experience in this is extremely limited, but what you should do in these situations is go through each point in the code step by step and seeing what it does. Usually you'll find that somewhere along the line the output of something isn't what you expect it to be and breaks the code. I spent about 5 minutes setting up the code and adding some print statements along the way to see the code output and immediately found the issue. https://repl.it/repls/MoistInstructiveIcelandichorse

Obviously operators[k][2] is being treated as a string rather than a list, so when you iterate through it, you'll be going through each character rather than each item. After a quick look at your list it seems like your list of operator expertise is a string and not a list. I'm not sure if that's intentional or not, but to make your code work you'll need to sort that out somehow.

Comment: Hi Slidy! Thank you so much for your answer. I have now edited and it's all fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I won't show any code in this answer, but a simple algorithmic approach that I would take. The rest will be up to you.

The approach I would take is as follows:

- Loop through the customers
- For each customer check what language the customer speaks.

  - Loop through the operators and check if each speaks the same language as the customer.
  - If a customer does, check if he/she covers the problem that the customer needs help with.
  - If he/she does, assign the operator to the customer. (I do not know how you would represent that, so I'll leave it like that.
- Repeat the process above for the next customer and until all customers are taken care of.

This algorithm that I just came up with is by no means perfect, but it should get the job done if this is what you are looking for.

The fun part is now implementing that (at least to me).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas! I followed your advice but my list stays blank, can you have a look at it? I have edited the post and added my code.

Comment: Sorry, I've been offline for a few days. 
It's been a while since I programmed python. That's why I didn't provide any code. I'm not sure I could help debug.